# take images in a folder into an array

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my android project, I have had to **store images from the *sd* card in to an *array***. I can filter and get all the images in the folder. But what i really need to do is **filter and get some specific images** instead of all the images. My code segment is,

```
File[] imagelist = filePath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  {  
                return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png")));
            }  
        });
```

So, can someone help me with some helpful code segment. Thank you!

Comment: You are already specifically getting jpg and png, so what extra critera are you looking for?

Comment: No, it takes all the JPEGs and PNGs. I don't want all of them. I just want to take few according to a database. insteadof  filter and take all the images, just want to take few. So can you help me.

Comment: How do you want to determine which few? The first few? What info does your database hold and how does it relate to images? Is it names? sizes? some other meta data? Do you have access to that info from the java, or is it stuck in the database?

Comment: Oh, in my case the names of relevant images for a sales item are stored in the database. I can get the names. But in some instance i don't need all the images in the folder. So i want to load only the images named in the database. So i can get the needed images according to the database. I want a way to filter the images from there names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if you have a list of names you want in a String array, then for every file that runs through the filter you will have to loop over the list and compare the name of the file against the array to see if it exists. If it does then its one you want.

```
File[] imagelist = filePath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
    if(!(name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".png")) return false; // Only need images
    for(String validName: namesArray){
      // If the names in the list include the file extention then use this line
      if(name.equals(validName)) return true;
      // Otherwise If the names in the list don't include the file extention then use these lines
      if(name.endsWith(".jpg") && name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".jpg")).equals(validName)) return true;
      if(name.endsWith(".png") && name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".png")).equals(validName)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to get the images by using switch statements. But the loop helps a lot by saving several lines of code. Thank you.